# Expandablelistview with images in Navigation drawer

Tags: android, image, navigation-drawer, expandablelistview

**issue** Different images for each item of expandable listview in Navigation drawer

tried almost every reference but i guess for my datasource its little tricky.

please suggest method or code for using icons for each list title

example:

```
image1 text1

image2 text2 

image3 text3 

imag4 text4 

image5 text5
```

Here's groupview of adapter

```
 @Override
    public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        String group = null;
        int id_res = 0;

        String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
            TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
            listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
        ImageView img=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image1);     <--- adding image here


        }


        return convertView;
    }
```

Here's my data source

```
public class ExpandableListDataSource {

    public static Map<String, List<String>> getData(Context context) {
        HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListData = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        List<String> menu = Arrays.asList(context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu));
        List<String> home = Arrays.asList(context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.home));
        List<String> one= Arrays.asList(context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.one));
        List<String> two= Arrays.asList(context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.two));
        List<String> three= Arrays.asList(context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.three));
        List<String> four= Arrays.asList(context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.four));
        List<String> five= Arrays.asList(context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.five));
        List<String> six = Arrays.asList(context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.six));

        expandableListData.put(menu.get(0), home);
        expandableListData.put(menu.get(1), one);
        expandableListData.put(menu.get(2), two);
        expandableListData.put(menu.get(3), three);
        expandableListData.put(menu.get(4), four);
        expandableListData.put(menu.get(5), five);
        expandableListData.put(menu.get(6), six);


        return expandableListData;
    }

}
```

Comment: Learn Custom Expandable ListView http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129

Comment: @sathish it has a method which is not applied here. as you see my datasource as listed differently. thinking to mcontext.getresources. getdrawable something like this

Comment: image from drawable or URIs@piyush_droid

Comment: @muruga5000 images from drawable. still cant figure out how to proceed with it